# iTextSharp 5.1.3 - Put HTML in Form Field using c#?

Tags: c#, html, pdf-generation, itext

I have a PDF Form and I'm trying to put HTML formatted text into a field using itextsharp 5.1.3 using c#.  I want the text to keep the same formatting as it has in the HTML.  How can I do this?

I've searched everywhere and I haven't been able to find anything.  The only examples I can find show how to convert an entire document, but none show a clear way to convert a string of HTML code to PDF format and set a Field with it.

Comment: are you talking about just adding Element(s) to the document..

Comment: No, I want to add the elements to a field in my PDF Form.

Comment: I just posted an example on how to add elements..

Comment: It doesn't show how to add elements to a field in a PDF Form.

Comment: Step 3 where it says add elements ... a paragraph is considered an element..

Comment: I don't think you understand. I need the elements to display inside of a field on a PDF Form.  Fields are pre-defined sections of a PDF document.

Comment: can you provide a screen shot.. perhaps I am misunderstand you.. sorry as I do not mean to frustrate you.. thanks

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm talking about... http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/PdfGenerator_CS06162007023347AM/PdfGenerator_CS.aspx

Comment: ok I see the example looks pretty straight forward.. so the html formatted text do you know what fields you want to place them in..? if so that example should be what you need.. instead of passing the Quoted String Text in that example .. pass the html formatted text as a variable .. I don't see why this should be so difficult